# how to avoid scroll down when chrome #urlbar hide

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

my website in mobile responsive scrolling even though I put body and html height to 100vh.

```
html,
body{
     height: 100vh
}
```

I also calculate chrome #urlbar but still scrolled

```
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {
    .fixed-view {
        height: calc(92vh - 56px);
    }
}
```

[my mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ggpx.jpg)
[mobile screen in show of chrome #urlbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcxf5.jpg)

Comment: that's my problem too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too, set style:

```css
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
```

That's enough.

Comment: such a short answer! :D thank you very much